# How do I factor the the following cubic polynomial: $x^3-12x^2+41x-42$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

$$x^3-12x^2+41x-42$$

What is the most efficient/easy way to do this?

Comment: $2$ seems to be a root.

Comment: Yes but what method should be used?

Comment: The rational root theorem gives you a limited set of possibilities.  Testing each one of them is usually productive for class problems with higher exponents than $2$.  It succeeds here.

Comment: @dominator maybe you need to reed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division It's synthetic division's method. I think it's the best method for to solve these problems.

Comment: Vieta's is an amazing tool that is largely hidden.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Observe that

$$x^3-12x^2+41x-42=$$

$$(x-4)^3-7(x-4)-6$$

Now, check the divisors of $ 6 $ which are roots of

$$y^3-7y-6$$

You will see that $ -1,-2$ and $3$ work.

the roots of the initial equation are then
$-1+4=3; \; -2+4=2 $ and $3+4=7$.

Without divisors, we have
$$y^3-7y-6=(y^3+1)-7(y+1)$$
$$=(y+1)(y^2-y+1-7)$$
$$=(y+1)(y+2)(y-3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Vieta's is really easy.

The sum of the roots is $-(-12) = 12$, and the product of the roots is $-(-42) = 42$.

Find three numbers that sum to $12$ and multiply to $42$. You should get $2, 3, \text{and } 7$.

Therefore, the factorization is $$(x-2)(x-3)(x-7)$$

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I will try this out. Does it work for any equation or just cubic?

Comment: @dominator It works for any equation. Check out this article: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Vieta%27s_Formulas.